# how many ordered triplets $<A,B,C>$ such that $A,B,C \subset[n]$ and $|A\cup B\cup C|=k $ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics

how many ordered triplets $<A,B,C>$ such that $A,B,C \subset[n]$ and $|A\cup B\cup C|=k $ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ are there?

I'm really having trouble with this one.
Of course $k$ has to be less or equal to $n$.

If $k=1$ for example then the solution is $3n$ because $A,B,C$ can each be any number in $[n]$ while the other two are $\emptyset$.

not sure how to approach the general case, even without the condition that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure your answer is right for $k=1$.  What if $A=C=\{m\}$ and $B$ is empty?

Comment: Your $k=1$ case is already wrong. The non-empty sets can be $A$, $B$, $C$, $AC$ or $BC$, giving $5n$ ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, pick which $k$ elements appear within $A\cup B\cup C$.

Next, for each element from those $k$ selected, decide which of the following cases it falls in:

- in $A$, not in $B$, in $C$
- in $A$, not in $B$, not in $C$
- not in $A$, in $B$, in $C$
- not in $A$, in $B$, not in $C$
- not in $A$, not in $B$, in $C$

Comment: so is it $5^{C(n,k)}$?

Comment: No.  How many elements are in the $k$ selected elements that we need to make a decision for?  There are $k$ elements in $k$ elements!  Not $\binom{n}{k}$.  There may have been $\binom{n}{k}$ *choices* for what those elements were, but do not confuse the number of elements with the number of ways of picking elements.  The $\binom{n}{k}$ comes into play for the first step where we pick what those $k$ elements were.

Comment: thanks my bad. Then perhaps $C(n,k) \cdot 5^k$?

Comment: That is now correct